# Estimate coin heads probability after having observed some data using Bayes theorem

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability

I've been working on a problem about coins and Bayes' theorem, but I'm getting some counterintuitive results. Here's the problem and what I've tried.

Imagine you have a coin, and you have no reasons to assume it's biased, so the prior is $P(heads) = 0.5$. Now imagine you've observed the data $D = \{heads:120, tails:100\}$, and you want to compute the expected heads probability after having observed this data. If we apply the Bayes rule we get

$$
P(head | D) = \frac{P(D|head) P(head)}{P(D)}
$$

where

- The prior is $P(head) = 0.5$, since we're assuming it's an unbiased coin. Therefore, $P(tail) = 0.5$ as well.
- The likelihood is $P(D|head) = Binomial(220, 100, 0.5) = \binom{220}{120}0.5^{120}0.5^{100}$
- $P(D) = P(D|head)P(head) + P(D|tail)P(tail)$, where $P(D|tail) = \binom{220}{100}0.5^{100}0.5^{120}$

If we plug everything in the Bayes rule we get

$$
P(head|D) 
=\frac{\binom{220}{120}0.5^{120}0.5^{100}0.5}{\binom{220}{120}0.5^{120}0.5^{100}0.5 + \binom{220}{100}0.5^{100}0.5^{120}0.5} 
= \frac{\binom{220}{120}}{\binom{220}{120} + \binom{220}{100}} 
= \frac{1}{2}
$$

That seems counterintuitive to me. I would expect a posterior probability higher than $0.5$, something around $120/220\approx 0.545$.

Notice also that if we change the observed data to $D=\{heads: 12000, tails: 10000\}$ the results are the same even if we have much more information.

How is this possible? Is there some error in my numbers? Did I understand something wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your prior asserts the coin is fair and offers no possibility of any other situation.  A more useful prior would allow for various chances of heads.  One standard such prior is the uniform (that is, Beta(1,1)) distribution on that chance.  See [our many posts on this topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=bayes+beta+binomial+posterior) for details.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @whuber. My question is then why does this approach work in some cases, like the typical examples with clinical tests (thttps://davidbieber.com/snippets/2022-07-12-medical-test-paradox-paradox/), where the prior offer no possibility of any other situation, but the posterior is different than the prior.

Comment: I am unable to see the connection, because there is no such prior applied in the link you give.  It is purely a probability calculation.

Comment: when in the post they say "Suppose 1 in 10000 people have a certain disease", isn't that a prior?

Comment: No, it's not.  That post does not concern estimating the frequency of disease in the population.

Comment: no ,but it's about estimating the probability of an individual of having the disease, and they use 1/10000 as a prior for that individual. Isn't that equivalent to the case of estimating the probability of a coin toss being head? Instead of disease/no disease and prior 1/10000, you have head/tail and prior 1/2. Maybe I'm missing something. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: The $1/10000$ is not a "prior:" it is *given* and not subject to estimation.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but in Bayes' theorem $P(d|p) = \frac{P(p|d) P(d)}{P(p)}$, where $d$ is `disease` and $p$ is `positive test`, isn't by definition $P(d)$ the prior? And in the case of medical tests, we choose $P(d) = \frac{1}{10000}$. What I'm missing here? Why is $\frac{1}{10000}$ not the prior?

Answer (score 1):

You’ve given a prior distribution of a fair coin and no possibility of an unfair coin. No matter what kind of data you get, you can’t overwhelm the certainty in your prior.

Remember that you’re putting a prior on the probability parameter $p$ of some $\text{Binomial}(n,p)$ distribution, rather than speculating what the probability of a coin flip coming up heads will be. If you have a strong belief (but not certainty) that the coin is fair, you might want a prior that has considerable density on or near $0.5$. If your prior belief about the coin is, “Gee, I don’t know,” then you might want to consider all possible values in the parameter space to be equally likely, which translates to a prior distribution on $p$ of $\text{U}(0,1)$ (which equivalent to $\text{Beta}(1,1)$).

Comment: ok! it makes sense, it's like if I had defined a delta prior at 0.5, so it's impossible to move it no matter how much data I observe. My question is now, why does this approach work in some cases, like the typical examples with clinical tests (https://towardsdatascience.com/bayes-theorem-for-medical-test-f1fb12b579c6), where the prior is still a delta but Bayes theorem works properly.

Comment: Which part of the article do you mean? @alexmolas

Comment: when they talk about the medical paradox @Dave

Comment: @alexmolas Then you're calculating one probability of an event, rather than a posterior distribution of a parameter. (Maybe one could argue that this is a posterior distribution with all density on one value, but whatever...)

Comment: and why I can't use the same approach to compute the probability of a "head" event? This is what I'm missing. Thanks :)

Comment: @alexmolas You are, and as with the medical example, you are getting exactly one number instead of a distribution over many numbers.